Custom arrows in text
I would like to draw an arrow which looks something like this:

Although I can draw it in tikz, I don't know how to make it intext. Like:
bla bla bla \fancyarrow bla bla bla

PS. Here's my approach of drawing them. Still have no idea on how to make them inline
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.375,0.25);
        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.375cm]
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.375,0.25);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Hi! Could you show us your TikZ code?

@CarLaTeX, hey! Just edited my post

Obligatory comprehensive symbols list link

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use one of the already existing macros, e.g. \faForward from the fontawesome5 package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
   bla bla bla \faForward\ bla bla bla 
\end{document}



To answer your actually question:
You can make a macro from your TikZ picture:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fancyarrow}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) -- (0,0.5em) -- (0.375em,0.25em);
        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.375em]
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) -- (0,0.5em) -- (0.375em,0.25em);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
bla bla bla \fancyarrow\ bla bla bla
\end{document}



Thank you very much for your answer!  That's exactly what I need

@DanielNeskorodov You're welcome!

I linked the second approach! You could even create rounded corners use \draw[fill=black, rounded corners=0.5pt] (0,0) -- (0,0.5em) -- (0.375em,0.25em) -- cycle;.

I'd use two \blacktriangleright symbols, with some negative space in between.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\dblbtriangleright}{%
  \blacktriangleright\joinrel\blacktriangleright
}

\begin{document}

$A \dblbtriangleright B$

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your answer!

@DanielNeskorodov I assumed it was intended as a math symbol. In case it isn't, just do \newcommand{\fancyarrowright}{\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright\joinrel\blacktriangleright}}

thank you, I will try both!
